# Access my college network via VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

I'd like to get a free VPN through my college but it seems that unlike most other colleges they don't have a VPN.

Is it possible to put their network details into The Windows 10 VPN and get it that way?

The subnet mask is 255.255.0.0. I don't know the server address though; would it be listed as DHCP server in the terminal?

Comment: *Their* network details is only for connecting to *their* network, not for remote access. If there's no VPN, there's isn't. I really don't know why you need to ask. And for whatever corporate network/resources, be it school, college or work or..., you IT department is where you should ask.

Comment: This question boils down to *"It is possible to configure a VPN connection using the settings of some random network?"*, which is not off-topic. (OTOH, it would be off-topic if it were asking "*How* can I connect to my school's network via VPN?")

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to put their network details into The Windows 10 VPN and get it that way?

## No.

Computers connect to a local network (LAN) differently than they do through a VPN. While the end result is the same (access to resources on the target network), the process by which connectivity is established is different.

Here is a high-level overview of that elucidates the differences between connecting directly to the target LAN (i.e. the University's network) and from a remote network such as a coffee shop via a VPN:

**Connect to target LAN (Direct)**

1. Connect network cable to target LAN (or connect via Wi-Fi)
2. Obtain TCP/IP address

**Connect to target LAN (via VPN)**

1. Connect network cable to local LAN (or connect via Wi-Fi)
2. Obtain TCP/IP address (including a gateway address)
3. Connect to target LAN via VPN (i.e. VPN software connects to public IP address of target LAN's VPN server)
4. Obtain TCP/IP address on target LAN

At the end of both of these processes, we can communicate via TCP/IP with other devices on the target LAN.

#### How this applies to your question

The "network details" that you have are those needed to establish a direct connection to the target network.  However, **this is of no use for establishing a VPN connection**. As shown in step #4, to access the target network via VPN, you must first connect to a VPN server that has been installed on the target network.  This VPN server must be accessible over the Internet, and to connect you must know it's Internet-facing IP address.  Without this information, you cannot establish a VPN connection.  Further, if a VPN server doesn't exist in the first place, then no such connection is possible.